# Scrolling window on mouse move only works when mouse is moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, scroll

I have a page that automatically scrolls based on mouse position. The code I am using is pretty simple, but it only works when the mouse is actually moving. The page stops scrolling whenever the mouse is completely still, which leads to a judder-y effect. I would like the scroll to continue to happen regardless of whether my mouse is moving or not.

This is my javascript (jQuery) code:

```
$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
  $('html, body').scrollTop(function (i, v) {
    var h = $(window).height();
    var y = e.clientY - h / 2;
    return v + y * 0.02;
  });
  $('html, body').scrollLeft(function (i, v) {
    var w = $(window).width();
    var x = e.clientX - w / 2;
    return v + x * 0.02;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Scrolling window on mouse move only works when mouse is moving

That's so.

You may decide to trigger the mousemove event manually. This is an attempt:

```js
$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
    $('html, body').scrollTop(function (i, v) {
        var h = $(window).height();
        var y = e.clientY - h / 2;
        return v + y * 0.02;
    });
    $('html, body').scrollLeft(function (i, v) {
        var w = $(window).width();
        var x = e.clientX - w / 2;
        return v + x * 0.02;
    });
});

var x = 1;
var y = 1;
setInterval(function() {
    x += 1;
    y += 100;
    event = $.Event('mousemove');
    event.clientX = x;
    event.clientY = y;
    $(document).trigger(event);
}, 300)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
<p>this is a paragragh</p>
```